# Why are some Windows shares not available?

Tags: windows-7, samba, file-sharing

I have a Windows 7 computer on my local network that hosts all my media. I've shared relevant folders there without any limitation, so anyone *should* be able to access the files without providing a login. (The WLAN itself has a passcode, so I don't need per-machine security.)

- I can see this Windows machine when I navigate to `network:///`.
- I can navigate into it and see a lot of shares in `smb://media-pc//`.
- I can open *some* of the shares, e.g. `smb://media-pc//Users/torben/`
  **but not** e.g. `smb://media-pc//media/`

  - I get the error:**Unable to mount location: Failed to mount Windows share**.

**Why can I access some of the Windows shares on this computer, but not others?**
I believe that I have shared them the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions issue on the Windows side. Can you access it via other Windows machines?

Check the permissions (read permissions) on the media directory since it isn't in the users home directory.